# How to position a div so that it always appear 100px from top of the visible display

Tags: javascript, css

I've a stream of updates just like a twitter stream.

```
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
</ul>
<div id="pop-up"></div>
```

And the CSS

```
#pop-up {
    position: absolute;
    top: 125px;
    left: center;
    margin-left: -200px;
    width: 960px;
    min-height: 400px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

When I click on the list-item, the `div#pop-up` will pop up as an overlay and content will be dynamically generated inside it.

How do I position the pop-up in such a way that it pops up in a 'fixed' position inside the screen??

I can not just write `position: fixed` as, if the content is long, then I've to be able to scroll down. And I can not write `position: absolute` as the list items is long and if I scroll down at the bottom and click on the last item of the list, the pop-up appears 150px from top and I've to scroll up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(window).scrollTop()` to get number of scrolled pixels and add 150 to it - that gives you `top` value of your absolutely positioned popup. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4zUeq/2/).

Answer (score 2):

> the list items is long and if I scroll down at the bottom and click on
>   the last item of the list, the pop-up appears 150px from top and I've
>   to scroll up?

To avoid this problem, you'll always have to stick with a `position:fixed` div. To make it scrollable, just add a quick `overflow: scroll` :) Easy as pie.

Comment: I actually would prefer the `#pop-up` to be scroller-free. That's what's creating the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#pop-up').hover(function(){
$(this).css('position','absolute');
},function(){
$(this).css('position','fixed');
});
```

That way, it is scrollable, once you enter and is running with the page, when you're outside